# Variable is not changing from subshell

Tags: bash

There is a simple code to demonstrate the problem:

```
[kan@altegom ~]$ ( A=1; ls | if true; then A=2; fi; echo $A; )
1
```

I expect output `2`, but because the `if` is executed in pipe (I think it instantiates a new shell), the variable assignment is not visible.

How could I change a variable from a pipe?

Comment: This might help: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32325/keep-global-variables-values-piping-through-functions

Comment: @AlbertoZaccagni Yes, seems it is impossible to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use process substitution instead:

```
( A=1; if true; then A=2; fi < <(ls); echo $A; )
```

Or here strings with command substitution:

```
( A=1; if true; then A=2; fi <<< "$(ls)"; echo $A; )
```

Comment: Yeah... I need the script working in mingw, it doesn't support process substitution unfortunately.

Comment: @kan Updated. You might try `here strings` with `command substitution`.

Answer (score 1):

Or parenthesize the second command:

```
( A=1; ls | { if true; then A=2; fi; echo $A; } )
```

Comment: You have placed echo inside the pipe's subshell. I need it outside. `( A=1; ls | (if true; then A=2; fi ) ; echo $A; )`. And in this case it works the same.

Comment: No, it doesn't work, try it, does the same as in my question.

Comment: $ ( A=1; ls | { if true; then A=2; fi; echo $A; } )

2

Comment: In your answer I need the `}` placed before `echo`, the `echo` should be outside the piped process. Only `if-fi` is in the pipe. echo just the next command after `ls`

Comment: I see.  The pipe creates a subprocess that can't affect the parent environment.  I guess you can treat the subprocess like a function, e.g. ( A=1; A=$(ls | if true; then echo 2; else echo $A; fi;) ; echo $A; ).